# UWP - Cant create a package under release mode in Visual Studio Enterprise Edition 2015

Tags: visual-studio-2015, release, uwp-xaml

Please see the screenshot of the error[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0uqDS.png)

Comment: I am trying to build a package for my app under release mode in VS enterprise edition 2015, but I cant create the package due to the errors in the screenshot. However, when it is in debug mode, it builds fine.

Comment: try enable .NET Native under debug mode and see if it makes any difference(report any error). This could also be a possible reason for your issue.

Comment: We can successfully create the package with the .NET Native enabled under bedug mode.  Only in the release mode, there are errors.

Comment: Well it sounds like a Visual Studio problem. Does uninstall and install Microsoft.NETCore.UniversalWindowsPlatform works for you? You can do this from Nuget package management tool

Comment: Yeah, I did that already. I was jumping from different version of Microsoft.NETCore.UniversalWindowsPlatform supported in VS 2015.

Answer (score 0):

Could you delete the x86 or x64 folder (whichever you are using) inside the "obj" folder of your project and then try to build it again. It usually works for me.

Comment: I cant find the "obj" folder in my project. Can you tell me where it usually can be found.